# JSP Page Error: NoClassDefFoundError: com.tridion.web.Admin

Tags: 2011, configuration, jsp

So on publishing a .jsp page I kept running into the error 'NoClassDefFoundError: com.tridion.web.Admin', while other pages which used the same templates, but contained different component presentations, worked fine.

```
Uncaught exception created in one of the service methods of the servlet
/en/contentlayouttesting/testFAQCategoryDetails.jsp in application project_war.
Exception created : com.ibm.websphere.servlet.error.ServletErrorReport:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.tridion.web.Admin

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.tridion.web.Admin (initialization failure)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:140)
    at com.tridion.web.jsp.JSPPage.getPresentation(JSPPage.java:266)
    at com.tridion.web.jsp.JSPPage.init(JSPPage.java:104)
    at com.tridion.web.jsp.JSPPage.<init>(JSPPage.java:68)
    at com.tridion.web.jsp.tag.ComponentPresentationHandler.doStartTag(ComponentPresentationHandler.java:47)
    at com.ibm._jsp._testFAQCategoryDetails._jspx_meth_tridion_ComponentPresentation_0(_testFAQCategoryDetails.java:248)
    at com.ibm._jsp._testFAQCategoryDetails._jspService(_testFAQCategoryDetails.java:146)
```

I have a feeling I am missing a file but after cross-referencing I have not been able to locate any missing jars.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After doing some research I have found that the problem is most often associated with a missing cd_wai.jar file, which houses the Admin.class file. However, this was not my problem. After searching through the various folders I saw that we were missing the cd_wai_conf.xml (configuration) file which resolved the issue.

Comment: This error also appears when the configuration files are not valid XML files.